# How can I modify my function to be able to cancel the interval from anywhere in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a countdown and I want to be able to cancel the interval not only when reach 0 but with clicking of a button as well.How can I modify my function to be able to cancel the interval from anywhere in the controller.

```
function countDown(total) {
total = total * 60;
var interval = $interval(function () {
    var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60);
    var seconds = total - minutes * 60;
    if (minutes < 1)
    {
        minutes = '0:';
    }
    else
    {
        minutes = minutes + ':';
    }

    if (seconds < 10)
    {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }

    self.remainingTime = "Remaining time: " + minutes + seconds;
    total--;

    if(minutes === '0:' && seconds === '00')
    {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

}

Comment: Make `interval` variable global. Then you can access it in other functions like `stopCountdown`.

Comment: Do you have a $scope or do you work with this ?

Comment: How can I make it global. Yes I do have $scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by other users, you should make `interval` global in the controller. Then on the other functions you  want to cancel the `interval` you can call it safely.

Take a look at the below sample:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($interval) {

    var self = this;

    var interval;

    self.wizard = {
      startInterval: startInterval,
      cancelInterval: cancelInterval
    };

    startInterval();

    return self.wizard;

    function startInterval() {
      countDown(24);
    }

    function cancelInterval() {
      $interval.cancel(interval);
    }


    function countDown(total) {
      cancelInterval();

      total = total * 60;
      interval = $interval(function() {
        var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60);
        var seconds = total - minutes * 60;
        if (minutes < 1) {
          minutes = '0:';
        } else {
          minutes = minutes + ':';
        }

        if (seconds < 10) {
          seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

        self.wizard.remainingTime = "Remaining time: " + minutes + seconds;
        total--;

        if (minutes === '0:' && seconds === '00') {
          $interval.cancel(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as ctrl">
<span ng-bind="ctrl.remainingTime"> </span>

<br/>

<a href="" ng-click="ctrl.cancelInterval()"> Cancel Interval </a>
<br/>

<a href="" ng-click="ctrl.startInterval()"> Start Interval </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you I followed your example, but when I cancel the interval and start a new countdown I am getting the following errors:angular.js:14328 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress, angular.js:14328 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: @user6934713, OK, I just updated the code for future readers. Now there is a `startInterval` function so you can reset the `interval` and refactored the code for using the `controller as` syntax as you are right now.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example using self instead of $scope like you are in your snippet above.  As others mentioned moving the interval var to the global scope fixes this.  I also added a stop and start function to test the issue you mentioned in the example above.

UPDATED - I added some code to the stop interval to reset the interval to undefined.  I found an example of this usage on Angular's site so it might be worth a try to see if it fixes your other issue.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('BaseController', function($interval) {
  var self = this;
  var interval;

  function countDown(total) {
    total = total * 60;
    interval = $interval(function() {
      var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60);
      var seconds = total - minutes * 60;
      if (minutes < 1) {
        minutes = '0:';
      } else {
        minutes = minutes + ':';
      }

      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
      }

      self.remainingTime = "Remaining time: " + minutes + seconds;
      total--;

      if (minutes === '0:' && seconds === '00') {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  self.stopInterval = function(){
    if (angular.isDefined(interval)) {
      $interval.cancel(interval);
      interval = undefined;
    }
  }

  self.startInterval = function(){
    countDown(10);
  }
});
```

Then in the html I added a button to start and stop the interval like so:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="BaseController as baseCtrl">
    {{ baseCtrl.remainingTime }}
    <div>
      <button ng-click="baseCtrl.startInterval()">Start Countdown</button>
      <button ng-click="baseCtrl.stopInterval()">Stop Countdown</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can view the codepen example [here](http://codepen.io/amartin007/pen/gWbbrv?editors=1111)

Comment: Thank you . I am calling a different function after I cancel the interval and I am getting this errors:angular.js:14328 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress,angular.js:14328 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress.

Comment: UPDATED - I added some code to the stop interval function to reset the interval to undefined.  I found an example of this usage on Angular's site so it might be worth a try to see if it fixes your issue above.